# Transform vector of Class to vector of decltype(Class::name()) by calling name() on every element

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, boost

Having the following struct `MyStruct`:

```
struct MyStruct {                                                                                                                                                                                      
  explicit MyStruct(std::string name) : name_(name){}
  std::string name() const { return name_; }
private:
  std::string name_;
};
```

I would like to transform a `std::vector` of `MyStruct`s to a `std::vector<std::string>`. I have managed to do it like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>

struct MyStruct {
  explicit MyStruct(std::string name) : name_(name){}
  std::string name() const { return name_; }
private:
  std::string name_;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<MyStruct> vm;
  vm.emplace_back("asd");
  vm.emplace_back("qwe");
  vm.emplace_back("zxc");

  using namespace boost::adaptors;
  auto vs = vm | transformed([](const MyStruct& c){return c.name();});

  for (const auto& c : vs) std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

but then `vs` is not a vector but a:

```
const boost::range_detail::transformed_range<(lambda at /tmp/main.cpp:21:36), std::vector<MyStruct, std::allocator<MyStruct> > > => const boost::range_detail::transformed_range<(lambda at /tmp/main.cpp:21:36), std::vector<MyStruct, std::allocator<MyStruct> > >
```

How can I achieve this? Preferably I would like to do it while initializing the vector - not by declaring vector and then `std::copy` or something similar.

I know that I can do something similar to:

```
std::vector<std::string> vv; 
vv.reserve(boost::size(vs));
boost::copy(vs, std::back_inserter(vv));
```

but I'd like a one step initialization (preferably with a `const` qualifier).

I believe this is some sort of a high order (functional) map function that I need or an std/boost/handwritten equivalent.

Comment: `begin` and `end` on the range should get you a pair of iterators. `std::vector` has a constructor taking a pair of iterators.

Comment: You can do `std::vector<std::string> vs; boost::copy(vm | transformed([](const MyStruct& c){return c.name();}), std::back_inserter(vs));`. I don't know of anything shorter than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend using [`range-v3`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/), which is basically the new and improved Boost.Ranges. There, it's just:

```
std::vector<std::string> vs = vm | ranges::view::transform(&MyStruct::name);
```

Note that if you captured this by `auto`, you wouldn't get a `vector`. The resulting object has a conversion operator.

With Boost.Ranges, you can't do that natively, but you can write your own piped adaptor:

```
struct make_vector_t
{
    template <class R>
    friend auto operator|(R&& range, make_vector_t)
    {
        using std::begin;
        using std::end;

        using value_type = typename iterator_traits<decltype(begin(range))>::value_type;
        return std::vector<value_type>(begin(range), end(range));
    }
} constexpr make_vector{};
```

and just use it:

```
auto vs = vm 
    | transformed([](const MyStruct& c){return c.name();});
    | make_vector;
```

Comment: Awesome. Can you explain what does this `friend` do in the beginning of function declaration?

Comment: @Patryk You need a non-member function, since the `make_vector_t` is going on the right.

Comment: I still not quite get it. Can you rephrase that?

Comment: I'd `decay` rather than `remove_reference`, or even better, use `iterator_traits<...>::value_type`.

Comment: @T.C. Yes to `iterator_traits` for sure.

Comment: @Patryk having `friend` there means it is declaring a non-member function which is a `friend` of the class.  To have operator overloads where the left-hand side is not your class, you have to use a non-member function, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421729#4421729) for more detailed description.

Comment: @M.M thanks. Finally it makes sense (+some lecture on cppreference)

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a helper class that acts as wrapper around `std::vector::iterator` that can be used to construct a `std::vector<std::string>` from a `std::vector<MyStruct>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct MyStruct {
  explicit MyStruct(std::string name) : name_(name){}
  std::string name() const { return name_; }
private:
  std::string name_;
};

// A minimal wrapper around std::vector::iterator
// to help with constructing a std::vector<std::string> from a 
// std::vector<MyStruct>

struct Iter 
{
   using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
   using value_type = std::string;
   using pointer = std::string*;
   using reference = std::string;
   using difference_type = long;

   Iter(std::vector<MyStruct>::iterator iter) : iter_(iter) {}
   std::string operator*() const { return (*iter_).name(); }
   bool operator!=(Iter const& rhs) const { return this->iter_ != rhs.iter_; }
   Iter& operator++() { ++iter_; return *this;}

   std::vector<MyStruct>::iterator iter_;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<MyStruct> vm;
  vm.emplace_back("asd");
  vm.emplace_back("qwe");
  vm.emplace_back("zxc");

  std::vector<std::string> vs(Iter(vm.begin()), Iter(vm.end()));
  for (const auto& c : vs) std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is that due to use of `std::string&` as the last parameter of  `std::iterator`?

Comment: I think you are saying that `operator->()` will not work because the function does not return a reference. Hence, you won't be able to modify the contents.

Comment: `operator->()` needs to eventually return a pointer. `std::string` isn't a pointer and it doesn't have an `operator->()` defined to keep searching.

Comment: @Barry, thanks for the LOTD :) I updated the answer to avoid that pitfall.

Answer (score 0):

If `range-v3` as [Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069064/barry) mentioend is not an option, why not just wrap your multi-line algorithm into a function call? E.g.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct MyStruct {
  MyStruct(std::string n) : m_name(n) {}
  std::string name() const { return m_name; }

  std::string m_name;
};

template <typename T> auto ExtractNames(const std::vector<T> &vm) {
  std::vector<decltype(std::declval<T>().name())> result(vm.size());
  std::transform(vm.begin(), vm.end(), result.begin(),
                 [](const T &v) { return v.name(); });

  return result;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<MyStruct> vm{{"asd"}, {"qwe"}, {"zxc"}};
  auto vs = ExtractNames(vm);

  for (auto &elem : vs) {
    std::cout << elem << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here in `ExtractNames` you're paying for default constructed values in returned vector before "transforming it into the desired one.

Comment: Would using ``std::back_inserter(result)`` help if you don't specify the count on ``result`` construction?

Comment: Sure. If you declare, reserve and then use back_inserter I think it'll be better

Answer (score 0):

Not as nice as solution based on ranges-v3, but it has the advantage to not need any 3rd party library:

```
const auto vs = [&]{
                    std::vector<std::string> t(mv.size());
                    std::transform(mv.begin(), mv.end(), t.begin(), [](auto& s) {return s.name(); });
                    return t;
                }();
```

You can of course use `reserve` and `back_inserter` to prevent default construction, but I'd actually time the code before prefering one over the other.